# Dll injection with GetFullPathNameA not working?

Tags: c++, dll

If I explicitly write the address the dll injection works

`char s[1000]="E:\\worldisnotenough.dll";   //Works`

If I use `GetFullPathNameA` DLL injections do not work, and they do not give any runtime or compile time errors. I checked this:

```
char s[1000];
int ax =GetFullPathNameA("worldisnotenough.dll",
                  1000,
                  s, //Output to save the full DLL path
                  NULL);

  std::cout<<s;  //prints the correct path. Working.
```

The line `cout << s` prints the correct path, but DLL injection doesn't happen. No errors occur. I checked VirtualAllocEx, WriteProcessMemory, and CreateRemoteThread, and all of them are working properly.

Edit: complete code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include<windows.h>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<iostream>
#include "E:/Users/Gen/qt project freiza/FreizaLibrary/freizalibrary.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
//    FreizaLibrary lib;
//    QTextStream s(stdin);
//    QString value = s.readLine();

//    lib.injection(value.toInt());
int procID = 13044;

  HANDLE  hHandle = OpenProcess( PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD |
                           PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                           PROCESS_VM_OPERATION |
                           PROCESS_VM_WRITE |
                           PROCESS_VM_READ,
                           FALSE,
                           procID );

  QString dllName = "worldisnotenough.dll";

  QFile myDllFile(dllName);
  QFileInfo dllInfo(dllName);
  QString str =dllInfo.absoluteFilePath();
  char s[]="E:\\Users\\Gen\\qt project freiza\\build-libtester-FreizaKit-Release\\release\\worldisnotenough.dll";
std::cout<<strlen(s)<<"\n";
  int ax =GetFullPathNameA("worldisnotenough.dll",
                  86,   //I set it to 1000 before posting this question.
                  s, //Output to save the full DLL path
                  NULL);
//qDebug()<< QString::fromUtf8(s) <<" "<< ax;
  std::cout<<s<<"size "<<ax;
  LPVOID dllPathAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hHandle,
                               0,
                               strlen(s),
                               MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT,
                               PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

std::cout<<" test \n";
std::cout<<(int*)dllPathAddr<<endl;
if(dllPathAddr==NULL)
{
    qDebug()<<"virtual failed";
}

size_t x;
 int n= WriteProcessMemory(hHandle,
                     dllPathAddr,
                     s,
                     strlen(s),
                     &x);

  if(n==0)
  {
      qDebug()<<"write failed";
  }
  std::cout<<endl<<n<<"\t"<<x;

  LPVOID addr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
  if(addr==NULL)
  {
      qDebug()<<"get proc failed";
  }

  HANDLE rThread = CreateRemoteThread(hHandle, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)addr,dllPathAddr, 0, NULL);
  if(rThread==NULL)
  {
      qDebug()<<"create remote failed";
  }
  WaitForSingleObject(rThread, INFINITE);
  VirtualFreeEx(hHandle, dllPathAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
CloseHandle(hHandle);
  qDebug()<< "done";
    return a.exec();
}
```

And why negative votes?
When I post full code. People say only post the segment of code which is not working.
And I explained the situation to its fullest. Because of these negative votes now I won't be able to ask questions on stackoverflow. Thank you.

Comment: Can you include the code where something isn't working? At what point do you detect that DLL injection does not happen? Can you set a breakpoint and verify that the contents of the `s` array are identical to the hard-coded version?

Comment: We need more code, if cout << s prints the correct value, then GetFullPathNameA is working correctly and the error is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: VirtualAllocEx returns an address. WriteProcessMemory returns number of bytes written, CreateRemoteThread returns a valid handle in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to use a statically defined character array as a buffer for GetFullPathNameA!

See here:

```
    char s[]="E:\\Users\\Gen\\qt project freiza\\build-libtester-FreizaKit-Release\\release\\worldisnotenough.dll";
std::cout<<strlen(s)<<"\n";
  int ax =GetFullPathNameA("worldisnotenough.dll",
                  86,   //1000 is no good, MAX_PATH is 260
                  s, //Using 's' as a buffer? Don't do that please!
                  NULL);
```

Furthermore when using the ANSI version which you are as denoted by the 'A' a maximum path length of 260 characters is the maximum. MAX_PATH==260

"In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend "\?\" "

Fixed code: (However I don't use QT so that is missing from here, shouldn't matter though as it wasn't used for anything needed for the injecting to work)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

HANDLE GetProcessHandle(wchar_t *ProcessName,ULONG *ReturnedProcessId);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ULONG procID;
    HANDLE hHandle=GetProcessHandle(L"ExeToInjectInto.exe",&procID);

    /*HANDLE hHandle=OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|
                               PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,procID);*/

    std::cout<<"handle: "<<hHandle<<" process ID: "<<procID<<"\n";

    char s[]="C:\\Users\\DBVM_OS\\CodeBlocksProjects\\HelpFreizaProject\\bin\\Debug\\mytestdll.dll";
    std::cout<<s<<"\n"<<strlen(s)<<"\n";

    //First Problem:
    /*In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters.
     To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend "\\?\"
    */
    //Second Problem:
    /* Don't use a defined static char[] as a buffer! allocate some memory or use the stack */
    //char s2[MAX_PATH];
    //int ax=GetFullPathNameA("mytestdll.dll",MAX_PATH,s2,0);

    char *s2=new char[MAX_PATH];
    if(s2==0) return 0;
    int ax=GetFullPathNameA("mytestdll.dll",MAX_PATH,s2,0);

    std::cout<<s2<<"\nsize returned: "<<ax<<" strlen: "<<strlen(s2)<<"\n";

    LPVOID dllPathAddr=VirtualAllocEx(hHandle,0,(strlen(s2)+1),MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    std::cout<<"Remotely Allocated String Address: \n";
    std::cout<<(int*)dllPathAddr<<"\n";

    if(dllPathAddr==0)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("VirtualAllocEx failed...");
        return 0;
    }

    SIZE_T x;
    BOOL n=WriteProcessMemory(hHandle,dllPathAddr,s2,(strlen(s2)+1),&x);
    if(n==FALSE)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("write failed");
        VirtualFreeEx(hHandle,dllPathAddr,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hHandle);
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout<<"WriteProcessMemory Success: "<<n<<", Bytes Written: "<<x<<"\n";

    LPVOID addr=(LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleW(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if(addr==0)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("get proc failed");
        VirtualFreeEx(hHandle,dllPathAddr,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hHandle);
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout<<"LoadLibraryA: "<<addr<<"\n";

    HANDLE rThread=CreateRemoteThread(hHandle,0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)addr,dllPathAddr,0,0);
    if(rThread==0)
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("create remote failed");
        VirtualFreeEx(hHandle,dllPathAddr,0,MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hHandle);
        return 0;
    }


    WaitForSingleObject(rThread,INFINITE);
    std::cout<<"DLL Should have been injected successfully at this point...\nFreeing remote string";

    BOOL freed=VirtualFreeEx(hHandle,dllPathAddr,0,MEM_RELEASE);
    if(freed==0) OutputDebugStringA("Freeing Remote String Failed...");

    delete[] s2; //if you dynamically allocated s2 like I've done...
    CloseHandle(hHandle);
    return 0;
}

HANDLE GetProcessHandle(wchar_t *ProcessName,ULONG *ReturnedProcessId)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32W pe;
    HANDLE Snap;

    ZeroMemory(&pe, sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W));
    pe.dwSize=sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);
    Snap=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);

    if(Snap==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return 0;

    BOOL bProcess=Process32FirstW(Snap,&pe);
    while(bProcess)
    {
        if(_wcsicmp(pe.szExeFile,ProcessName)==0)
        {
            HANDLE ProcessHandle=OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|
                               PROCESS_VM_WRITE|PROCESS_VM_READ,FALSE,pe.th32ProcessID);

            if(ReturnedProcessId!=0)
                *ReturnedProcessId=pe.th32ProcessID;

            CloseHandle(Snap);
            return ProcessHandle;
        }

        bProcess=Process32NextW(Snap, &pe);
    }
    if(ReturnedProcessId!=0) *ReturnedProcessId=0;
    CloseHandle(Snap);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use

```
 strlen(s)+1
```

cause it returnes the lenght of the string without including the terminating null character itself! So VirtualAllocEx and WriteProcessMemory will not write the '\0' char and the filename will terminate at a "random" position in memory.

Also

```
 char s[]="E:\\Users\\Gen\\qt project freiza\\build-libtester-FreizaKit-Release\\release\\worldisnotenough.dll"; //- Length: 93+1

 int ax =GetFullPathNameA("worldisnotenough.dll",
              sizeof(s), //<-- old: 86 but s[] is 93 + 1 if this has to hold the total path may it was to small?
              s, //Output to save the full DLL path
              NULL);
```

looks wong?!

Comment: Yes replaced all strlen with strlen(s)+1, still it doesn't work.